# Totalizar resultados por produtos em tabela oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas semelhantes as tabelas abaixo:

```
TGFCAB

|NUNOTA|   DTMOV  |
------------------|
|  1   |01/06/2019|
|  2   |02/06/2019|
|  3   |03/06/2019|


TGFITE
|NUNOTA|CODPROD|QTDNEG|VLRUNIT |VLRTOTAL|
|------|-------|------|--------|--------|
|  1   |  18   |5,2   |10      |52      |
|  1   |  26   |1,3   |10      |13      |
|  2   |  11   |10,5  |10      |105     |   
|  2   |  26   |16,5  |10      |165     |
|  2   |  18   |2,5   |10      |250     |
|  3   |  18   |2,0   |10      |200     |
```

Eu não estou conseguindo realizar um SELECT para obter o total de valores de um determinado produto, a soma de todos os valores totais e o total de itens negociados, em exemplo.

Preciso realizar um select de forma que eu tenha o seguinte resultado.

```
|COD PROD|VLRTOTALPROD|
|18      |502         |
|26      |178         |
|11      |105         |
|TOTAL   |785         |
```

Porém não consigo filtrar mesmo com as requisições abaixo.

```
SUM(QTDNEG) AS TOTALNEG,
SUM(CASE WHEN TGFITE.CODPROD = 18 THEN QTDNEG ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALPRODUM
SUM(CASE WHEN TGFITE.CODPROD = 26 THEN QTDNEG ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALPRODDO
SUM(CASE WHEN TGFITE.CODPROD = 11 THEN QTDNEG ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALPRODTR
```

As informações acima são somente para ilustrar, o real select é o abaixo.

```
SELECT 
    DTMOV,
    TGFITE.NUNOTA,
    CODTIPOPER,
    TGFITE.CODEMP,
    NUMNOTA,
    DTNEG,
    QTDNEG,
    VLRUNIT,
    VLRTOT,
    CODVOL,
    PRODUTONFE,
    TGFCAB.DTMOV,
    SUM(QTDNEG) AS TOTALNEG,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TGFITE.PRODUTONFE = 190 THEN QTDNEG ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
        TGFCAB INNER JOIN TGFITE ON (TGFCAB.NUNOTA = TGFITE.NUNOTA) 
WHERE TGFCAB.DTMOV BETWEEN :PERINI AND :PERFIM 
        AND TGFCAB.CODTIPOPER IN (401, 18, 47, 103, 102, 36, 501)
GROUP BY DTMOV, TGFITE.NUNOTA, CODTIPOPER, TGFITE.CODEMP, NUMNOTA, DTNEG, QTDNEG, 
VLRUNIT, VLRTOT, CODVOL, PRODUTONFE, TGFCAB.DTMOV
```

Comment: não seria mais simples agrupar por produto e somar? algo assim: `select CODPROD, sum(QTDNEG) group by CODPROD`? só uma sugestão, pq para cada novo produto vai ter de mudar a query, e com o group não

Comment: @RicardoPontual o problema é que este exemplo é bem minimalista ao que eu tenho que buscar, meu select tem aproximadamente 12 colunas, eu não sei como fazer isso, vou postar abaixo mais ou menos como está aqui,

Comment: Qual o sentido de você colocar o campo QTDNEG como um dos campos da cláusula GROUP BY e também colocar este campo na função de agregação SUM?

Comment: Pois preciso agrupar os itens pela quantidade negociada, esta é a quantidade vendida, ou seja, se eu tenho duas vendas do produto a, com quantidades 10 e 10, eu vendi 20 unidades do produto a. Esta é a informação que eu preciso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nas analytic function do Oracle https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions